# How to flatten this OCT image with respect to the marked line

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am working on a medical image processing project where I have to use retinal OCT images. I am using the dataset available [here](https://people.duke.edu/~sf59/RPEDC_Ophth_2013_dataset.htm). This dataset has a lot of images and I want to flatten all of them. I have a flattening code which works correctly only for some images but fails as a generalised solution to all the provided images:

For instance, if the input image is:

[image: Input image]

The output after flattening is:

[image: Flattened image]

The code that I had used for performing the flattening process is:

```
function img_shift = img_flatten(img)
%img = rgb2gray(imread('retina.png'));

    % Find bottom line indices
    %find the location of the curve which is white/gray in color different
    %from the black 
    threshold = 100;
    retina = NaN(1, size(img,2));
    for j = 1:size(img,2)
        retina(j) = find(img(:,j) >= threshold, 1, 'last');
    end

    % Fit polynomial
    x = 1:length(retina);
    p = polyfit(x, retina, 2);
    retina_fit = round(polyval(p, x));

    % Plot the fit of the retina
    %figure(1);
    %plot([retina', retina_fit']);

    % Shift the data in the image
    img_shift = zeros(size(img), 'uint8');

    for j = 1:length(retina_fit)
     img_shift(:,j) = circshift(img(:,j), -retina_fit(j));
    end%for j

    % Plot the image
    %figure(2);
   % subplot(2,1,1);
    %imshow(img,[]);
    %subplot(2,1,2);
    imshow(img_shift);
end
```

I tried changing the **threshold** but it didn't make any difference to the code.

I have the following questions regarding my code:

1) Is there any other better method to perform flattening of OCT images?

2) Can I tweak my code to have a generalized flattening code for all the images belonging to the dataset?

Comment: out of interest, what's OCT?

Comment: Hey, @MarcusMüller,  OCT stands for **optical coherence tomography** which is a technique for taking scans of retina region of the eye for identifying and detecting different pathologies affecting the eye and other organs. I am linking the [https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Optical_coherence_tomography](Wikiwand article) for the interest of everyone.

Comment: How do you solve this problem?

Comment: @zcx, I used this approach: https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/8nqx4f/how_to_flatten_the_retinal_curves_in_the_oct_image/

Comment: I have the same problem but I am curious did you find a solution?

Comment: @emre Welcome to SE.SP! Please do not post a comment as an answer to the question. This site is **not** a discussion forum.  Please lurk a bit and try answering some questions or editing older posts to get enough reputation to comment.